# Can AWS Lambda functions be invoked as a background service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am new to Lambda functions, and am using the [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) framework to create them, specifically using python.  I am trying to create a function that will do some heavy processing of a file.  The type of work is not important, but each job might take several minutes to complete.

I'd prefer not to have an invocation request open for so long, and instead I'd like the Lambda to return immediately, but continue processing after it has returned.  Once the job is done, it could email me the processed file using SMS, for example.

Is this possible with AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda supports two invocation types:

- **RequestResponse**
- **Event**

`RequestResponse` will wait until the Lambda invocation is finished before returning the response. `Event` will invoke the Lambda function and then return a success status indicating that the function was successfully started. You can read more about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/).

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact, Lambda functions are ‘almost’ always requested asynchronously.

For your specific use case, you can have the lambda be ‘triggered’ when a file is uploaded to s3 (instead of invoking it programmatically). This means every time a file is uploaded to s3, the lambda is triggered and will process the file.

That way, no connection is open for the duration of that processing. The function can then notify it once it has completed.